# Behaviour of "go mod tidy" vs "go build"

Tags: go, go-modules

Suppose I have a project with the following structure:

```
+-- app/
+-- otherstuff/
+-- test/
+-- go.mod
+-- go.sum
+-- main.go
```

I can make sure `go.mod` does not contain unused dependencies by running `go mod tidy`:

```
# 1) Verify that no dependency containing the name "modern-go" is found on go.mod
$ grep 'modern-go' go.mod
<-- Empty (nothing found) (OK)


# 2) Run "go mod tidy", verify that nothing changes (i.e. go.mod is already clean)
$ go mod tidy -v
unused github.com/modern-go/concurrent
unused github.com/modern-go/reflect2
<-- messages above are displayed, but go.mod did not change


# 3) Verify that go.mod did not change
$ grep 'modern-go' go.mod
<-- Empty (nothing found) (OK)
```

Now, if I run `go build`, `go.mod` gets updated:

```
# 4) Run "go build"
$ go build


# 5) go.mod was updated by "go build":
$ grep 'modern-go' go.mod
    github.com/modern-go/concurrent v0.0.0-20180306012644-bacd9c7ef1dd // indirect
    github.com/modern-go/reflect2 v1.0.1 // indirect
```

I can't figure out what's going on here. I expected `go mod tidy` would leave `go.mod` on a clean state, and that running `go build` would therefore not change it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you running the current release of Go?

Comment: `go version go1.12.7 linux/amd64`

Comment: Have you had a chance to try with Go 1.13?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The behavior you’re expecting is usually true.

Go 1.13 has some fixes in this area. I would suggest trying with that:

https://twitter.com/golang/status/1164276194524762113

Comment: I don't see how this answers anything. Do you want to confirm that this is a bug in Go?